# how to give a name to downloaded file with async tornado client

Tags: python, tornado

i have some python tornado code that i use to get files async

```
from tornado import ioloop , httpclient
def get_file(url):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch(url,done)

def done()
    print "Done"
url = "http://localhost/files/ldfhgdksgfjkdfadf/output.pdf"
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

what happens is that the file gets saved in the current dir as "output.pdf", is there any way with asynchttp client to specify a file name? if i could i would call the file by some name and save it in a different directory other than the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reading `response.body` in the specified callback and write it to the appropriate file, e.g.:

```
from tornado import ioloop, httpclient


def get_file(url):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch(url, callback=done)


def done(response):
    with open("my_favorite_directory/my_favorite_filename.pdf", "w") as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    print "DONE"


get_file("http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf")
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```